# How can I replace special characters by regex and Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, regex

String: `abc2_2fkf-lo`

Now I want to use regex to delete the special characters as _ and -

The expect string as I want: `abc22fkflo`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`.

```
NSString *string = @"abc2_2fkf-lo";
NSString *updated = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[-_]" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
```

This replaces any occurrence of a `-` or `_` character with the empty string.

Note that if you want to match a `-` character using `[ ]` in a regular expression, the `-` needs to be the first character to avoid its normal special use as a character range operator.